# How to install multisim in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: virtualbox, xubuntu, playonlinux

I am new to ubuntu. I have already installed playonlinux and virtualbox but i have still not used them . Now, in our college they told us to install multisim . How should i install it in my laptop? Please I require step by step instruction as i a so new to ubuntu .

Comment: See https://knowledge.ni.com/KnowledgeArticleDetails?id=kA00Z0000019QhDSAU or try with clean Wine prefix (as with any other POL application).

Comment: No. I am not able to view it..